# Not able to use dynamic SQL in bulk collect and forall

Tags: plsql

Hi friends am writing a stored procedure that selects and inserts data from one table to another table in the same database but different users, to speed up the insert am trying to use bulk collect and forall but the problem is am using dynamic SQL in the procedure that picks table name, it's corresponding primary key name and the date validation columns from another status table

For eg: consider the following query

```
Select empid from emp_tab where trunc(insert_time)=trunc(sysdate)
```

Here the **PRIMARY KEY** - `empid`, **TABLENAME**- `emp_tab`, **date validation column** - `insert_time` will be dynamically picked by the procedure during run time of the procedure from another status table but am not able incorporate the `bulk collect` and `forall` into dynamic SQL for `bulk collect` am getting

> inconsistent data type

error and `forall` am getting

> virtual column

error

Does `bulk` and `forall` supports dynamic sql????
If not then is there any other way to speed up the insert like `forall`

Any suggestions are welcome
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your code using `FORALL` . Without the code we won't be able to help.

Comment: If you are generating code then you might as well generate `insert into y select a,b,c from x`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. Despite `BULK COLLECT` being a powerful tool, it can be tricky with all its limitation. Here is a example using `REF CURSOR`, but you can build the `TYPES` according to your necessity.

```
-- create source data
CREATE TABLE temp_table_source AS 
  (SELECT ROWNUM                            id, 
          dbms_random.String('U', 10)       name, 
          Round(dbms_random.Value(1, 7000)) salary 
   FROM   dual 
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5000 -- number of rows for the test
  );

-- create destination table (empty)
CREATE TABLE temp_table_dest AS 
  SELECT * FROM temp_table_source WHERE 1 = 2;

-- Dynamic bulk anonymous block
DECLARE
  v_stmt VARCHAR2(100);
  v_insert VARCHAR2(100);
  TYPE rec_source IS RECORD ( -- a type to represent your data
    id temp_table_source.id%TYPE,
    name temp_table_source.name%TYPE,
    salary temp_table_source.salary%TYPE
    ); 
  TYPE t_source IS TABLE OF rec_source;
  m_source t_source;
  TYPE l_cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
  l_cursor l_cursor_type;
BEGIN
  v_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM temp_table_source where 1 = :x';
  v_insert := 'INSERT INTO temp_table_dest (id, name, salary) VALUES (:a, :b, :c)';

  OPEN l_cursor FOR v_stmt USING 1; -- example of filtering
  LOOP -- use limits to test performance, but the LOOP is optional
    FETCH l_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO m_source LIMIT 1000; 
    --
    FORALL i IN 1 .. m_source.COUNT 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_insert 
        USING m_source(i).id, m_source(i).name, m_source(i).salary;
    --  
    COMMIT;
    EXIT WHEN m_source.COUNT = 0;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

-- See the result
Select count(1) from temp_table_dest;
```

If you need a dynamic `TYPE` as well, you will need to create it and drop at the end of your procedure instead of declare it in your package.

Comment: Hi Gabriel kindly guide me how to create and drop dynamic type at the end of my procedure, that's is my main problem

Comment: Am getting bind variable does not exist error in open cursor statement

Comment: You can use [this link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_create_type.htm) to see how the DDL for Types works. Basically you can create your DDL command as string/varchar2 and call it with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as the example above. Just make sure to store the name of your temporary type so you can drop it at the end of your procedure.
I'll work in put that on the example later.